# How to use Group By in LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, group-by

There is linq query in my existing project, something like this:

```
group new {a.name,a,description,a.number,i.productname}
by new {i.productname} into grpProduct
```

There is a Group By in my query and its syntax is like above query. Means it's using `group new` and after that `by new`. But I am not getting the purpose of this syntax. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you had a class like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And you defined a list and added some students to it...

```
var students = new List<Student>();
```

And then you created groups from it like this:

```
var i = (from s in students
         group new { s.Id, s.Name }
         by new { s.Age });
```

The `by new` section specifies the key(s) by which you'd like to create the grouping. So when you execute the query, you'll get one group per `Age`, and `Age` will be the "key" for each group.

*(Since there's only one field specified, you could rewrite that part as* `by s.Age` *.)*

The `group new` section specifies what you'd like to have available in each "group". Whereas `Age` will be the key, when you drill down into each group you'll have a collection of an anonymous type that includes `Id` and `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

The `by` statement declares what will be the key value used to group your data, while the `group` statement selects what will be "grouped". So your result is going to be a `IGrouping` on `i.productname` (it will be the key) and if you fetch each a these grouped items you will access to all the `new {a.name,a,description,a.number,i.productname}` objects with `i.productname` corresponding to this key.

Comment: ,can you suggest me a way to convert this query in simple sql query ?

Comment: Of course. Hopefully, the `group by` statement in SQL is a bit easier: 
   `select a.name,a.description,a.number,i.productname
   from table a, table i
   join ...
   group by i.productname;`
Here the `group by` and the `select` are distinct.